# Should l make Spring Model class with one field?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I don't know should i make class with only one field which l will use as @ModelAttribute to get data from jsp? for example:

```
public class Age {
private int number;

public int getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(int number) {
    this.number = number;
}}
```

And then using spring mvc form tag to fill this ModuleAttribute

```
<form:form action="processForm" modelAttribute="age">

<form:input path="number"/>
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to create a controller :

```
@Controller
public class AgeController {

    // this is to create an instance of Age and set in the model. 
    @RequestMapping("showForm")
    public String showForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("age", new Age());
        return "form"; // return form page.
    }

    // this is to print the age in the display page.
    @RequestMapping("processForm")
    public String processForm(@ModelAttribute("age") Age age) {
        return "display"; // return display page where you will display the data populated in the form page.
    }

}
```

Now, form page should look like :

```
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <!-- When you enter the data here, Spring will set the data in the Age bean by calling respective setter of the data members -->
 <body>
     <form:form action="processForm" modelAttribute="age">
       Enter an age : <form:input path="number" />
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
     </form:form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Now, display page should look like :

```
<%@taglib prefix="core" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
     The age is : ${age.number} <!-- Here getter is called internally -->
 </body>
</html>
```

On clicking the submit, the display page will show the data.